# What are some good books on oncology?

Tags: physiology, cancer, medicine

I'm looking for some book suggestions on oncology, preferably I want them to be fairly recent. I am not worried if they are fairly technical, as long as they have good accurate content and layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try *DeVita, Hellman, and Rosenberg's Cancer: Principles & Practice of Oncology*. It has detailed information on both biological and clinical aspects of cancer. Apparently, the [publishers](https://shop.lww.com/DeVita--Hellman--and-Rosenberg-s-Cancer--Principles---Practice-of-Oncology/p/9781496394637) regularly release online updates to cover the latest developments in oncology.

**Reference to the current edition:**

DeVita VT, Rosenberg SA, Lawrence TS, editors. DeVita, Hellman, and Rosenberg's cancer: principles & practice of oncology. 11th Edition. Philadelphia: Wolters Kluwer; 2018. 2432 p.

Answer (score 0):

The must-have textbook: **The Biology of Cancer** from Robert Weinberg

https://www.routledge.com/The-Biology-of-Cancer/Weinberg-Weinberg/p/book/9780429258794

The Second Edition was published in 2013, I didn't heard about a newer Edition yet but the current one is well recognized in the field[image]